# PIG Game Java code; Can you help me?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

```
public class Pig 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int turnScores = 0;
  int totalScores = 0;
  int turnScores2 = 0;
  int totalScores2 = 0;
  int dice;
  int dice2;
  String input = "r";
  char repeat;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  Random randomNumbers = new Random();

  System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Pig!\n");

  while(totalScores < 100 || totalScores2 < 100)
  {
      //human's turn
      do
      {
          dice = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1;

          System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice);

          if(dice == 1)
          {
              turnScores = 0;
              System.out.print("Your lose your turn!");
              System.out.println("Your Total is " + totalScores);
              break;
          }
          else
          {         
             turnScores += dice;
             System.out.print("Your turn score is " + turnScores);
             System.out.println(" and your total scores is " + totalScores);
             System.out.println("If you hold, you will have " + turnScores 
                               + " points.");
             System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, 'h' to hold.");
             input = keyboard.nextLine();
             repeat = input.charAt(0);

             if(repeat == 'h')
             {
                break;
             }
          }
      }while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice != 1);               

         totalScores += turnScores;
         System.out.println("Your scroes is " + totalScores);
      if(totalScores >= 100)
      {
          System.out.println("Your total Scores is " + totalScores);
          System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
          break;            
      }

      //computer's turn
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("It is the compuer's turn.");
      do
      {
          dice2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1; 
          System.out.println("The computer rolled: " + dice2);

          if(dice2 == 1)
          {
              turnScores2 = 0;
              System.out.print("The computer lost its turs!");
              System.out.println(" Computer total is " + totalScores2);
              break;             
          }
          else
          {
              turnScores2 += dice2;
              if(turnScores2 >= 20 || (totalScores2 + turnScores2) >= 100 )
              {
                  System.out.println("The computer holds");
                  break;      
              }
          }
       }while(dice2 != 1 || turnScores2 < 20);
      totalScores2 += turnScores2;
      System.out.println("The computer's scores is " + totalScores2 + "\n");

      if(totalScores2 >= 100);
      {
         System.out.println("THE COMPUTER WINS!");
         break;
      }
  }

 }
}
```

These are my statements. I don't know why my statements don't loop.
My result is:

> ```
> Welcome to the game of Pig!
>
> You rolled: 4
> Your turn score is 4 and your total scores is 0
> If you hold, you will have 4 points.
> Enter 'r' to roll again, 'h' to hold.
> h
> Your score is 4
>
> It is the computer's turn.
> The computer rolled: 6
> The computer rolled: 4
> The computer rolled: 2
> The computer rolled: 5
> The computer rolled: 5
> The computer holds
> The computer's scores is 22
>
> THE COMPUTER WINS!
> ```

Comment: First, Javascript is NOT Java - please remove that tag from your question.

Comment: Your final if statement ( if(totalScores2 >= 100 ) is closed off because you have a semi colon after it. Delete that.

Comment: I rolled the question back.  If someone helped you out, accept their answer; don't destroy the original question.

Answer (score 1):

As I said earlier, you MUST remove the semi colon from the end of this statement:

```
if(totalScores2 >= 100);
```

If that statement isn't remove, your if statement is taken as a closed off statement, skipped, the print statement is executed and then `break` is executed. As at that stage you are in the overall `while` loop, break will simply exit the system

However, even fixing that won't make the game function quite right. This is because you only reset the `turnScores` when the dice roll = 1. This isn't right.

If I get a turn score of 20 and choose to hold, that needs to be reset to 0, otherwise when I start my next go I'll already have 20 points to begin with.

The solution is to reset the turnScore just after the print statement of the scores at the end of the turn like this:

```
totalScores += turnScores;
System.out.println("Your scroes is " + totalScores);
turnScores = 0;
```

And then for the computer:

```
totalScores2 += turnScores2;
System.out.println("The computer's scores is " + totalScores2 + "\n");
turnScores2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

it took me forever to notice `if(totalScores2 >= 100);` has ";" in the end. remove it or otherwise the if statement is meaningless